# Why are watched tags now yellow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the wake of the Top Questions debacle, I refresh the Top Questions list today to find watched tags glowing yellow:

[image]

While I understand the impetus, the implementation is way overkill -- especially for the Dark-Theme. It's hard to envision a more harsh contrast than yellow on a dark background.

I'm glad there are new ideas for the Top Questions list, but we also have to be mature enough to know not all great ideas are improvements. It would really be nice if there was a preview we could comment on as a community to help with the Top Questions list. That may generate new ideas on how any change can be made better, help put the brakes on changes that are not improvements, or catch theme issue before they go live.

Can we make the watched tag color a preference in settings so those that don't like the color-shock can turn it off?

I'd also vote for making the old Top Questions layout an option as well -- it was very well like by many compared to the new. At least that provides users a choice in how things are displayed and the ability to recover some of the lost screen real estate for laptops.

I find scanning the new layout awkward compared to the old - most notably because the layout is inconsistent based on the length of the title. The author jumps up and down a line depending on whether the title wraps. It should be it's own `<div>` anchored to the bottom right of the question box instead of having the placement change based on whether or not the title wraps.

Don't take this as a complaint. I appreciate how hard it is to come up with ideas that satisfy a majority of the community. Making some of these changes preferences may be a way do make everyone happy.

Comment: Looks like it's in as just the yellow CSS variable, not a theme-dependent color variable. Somebody on the dev team forgot themes exist. :D

Comment: I guess we are going to have to remove all the watched tags in order not to be a part of this weird experiment going on right now.

Comment: I'm also finding it quite distracting. Just having the eye in the tag to indicate watched would be sufficient for me.

Comment: I find it much better when I change only the `color` to yellow, instead of the `background-color`. The default background with the same yellow as color looks nice in Dark Mode, IMO.

Comment: So upvote the existing posts about this issue by [DBS](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375637/289905), [0stone0](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375638/289905), [Tschallacka](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375639/289905), and [Rubén](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/375642/289905) — already [meta-tag:status-review].

Comment: May I recommend trying [my dark mode](https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-exchange-dark-mode) instead?

Comment: Dare I say it's worse in the light threme.

Comment: oh for God's sake can you please stop using extreme warning/alert color tones out of context in the ui?

Comment: It looks like a gold badge...? Also, I find the contrast between the white text (in the default light theme) and that yellow background to (literally) be physically painful to look at, so that's not good.

Comment: A few thoughts about this whole "watched" UI thing. 1) Are there actually any users of this site who don't know which tags they are watching? 2) Are people actually browsing the site by checking the top questions list at https://stackoverflow.com and then scroll down until they find something interesting? I thought the vast majority clicked on their watched tags to bring up every question about that specific topic, then move on to the next tag of interest. At least that's how I always used the site myself. The main page drowns in a flood of things I have no interest in.

Comment: I feel more like it is "watching" me rather than I am "watching" it.

Comment: Well, I for one think that this is way better than the big gold WATCHED we had before which I had absolutely no idea what it meant (at first I thought it was for bookmarked questions!). At least now it's clear it refers to tags. And does not change left stats layout.

Comment: @Lundin *"Are people actually browsing the site by checking the top questions list at stackoverflow.com and then scroll down until they find something interesting?"* If you watch enough tags, the home page will be almost exclusively questions with watched tags. So yes, there are lots of people (including me) who mainly find questions of interest from the home page.

Comment: When [this pull request](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/844) is merged and the changes are deployed, [the watched tags will have no colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98x0Q.png).

Comment: @Lundin that's the way I've used StackOverflow from the start.  They appear to prioritize the questions with tags you're watching, and deemphasize the colors of questions that don't match.  About 80% of what I see on that page is at least moderately interesting.

Comment: I guess the crux of the issue is why is it needed at all. It duplicates the enhanced contrast that the question highlight for watched tags already provides. That question highlight is non-intrusive and provides a quick and pleasant way to identify tags you watch. The addition of yellow over the tag icon isn't needed. It duplicates what the question highlight already does. I know we are down in the weeds here -- but if the goal is to make the SO/SE sites as good as can be, then this is part of the process. Take the best of the ideas, and provide options for what should be optional.

Comment: Gone now for me. Halleluiah. Now they just need to undo the watching eye icons.

Answer (score 22):

I remember seeing this as a suggestion in one of the discussions about the new layout of the top questions page.

I think it's an OK idea, but the chosen color is too garish.  I'd appreciate a little less contrast.

Answer (score 12):

I think that is a improvement over the previous approach, but far from good. I suggested it in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415649/why-are-watched-tags-now-yellow?cb=1#comment892079_415649) and, as I haven't seen a screenshot with such suggestion, I'd like to post it here. I just changed the `color` to the current yellow `background-color` and used the default `background-color`. LGTM in Dark Mode.

[image]

Comment: It's rather unreadable in light mode. But it does look good in dark, I agree.

Comment: this looks terrible even in dark mode

Answer (score 3):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)

can we please at the very least make the text line up with the centre of the eye image

[image]

Comment: It's the eye that is out of alignment, not the tag name text.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wanting to completely undo this with a custom user style (e.g. via the Stylus browser add-on or similar), here is the requisite CSS:

```css
a.post-tag.s-tag__watched, a.post-tag.s-tag__watched:hover {
    background-color: var(--theme-tag-background-color);
    color: var(--theme-tag-color);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .4em .5em;
}
a.post-tag.s-tag__watched::before {
    position: static;
    display: inline;
}
```

I have it applied to the URLs of `https://stackoverflow.com/` and `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/`

No information will be lost by using these reversion styles, since the default site styles still change the background color of the entire "row" div for questions with followed tags.

Answer (score -1):

I thought that is a huge improvement over the previous "Watched" big and ugly sign.

Comment: How so? The problem was that the most insignificant thing was yelling "ACTION NEEDED", still hasn't changed. Just the "eye" icon maybe with some subtly different shade from regular tags would have been enough.

Comment: It's better because it's not making the question take up that much more space. Note, "better" is not necessarily "good".

Comment: It's also better because now it is clear it's a tag thing. When I first saw the "Watched" badge next to a question, I thought it meant I was "following" that question (bookmarked, commented, whatever). It wasn't until I read some comments in the Meta thread that I learned its purpose.

Comment: At least it isn't monochrome, nondescript icons of hamburgers so I can live with it as well. I agree that it is an improvement over the previous experiment.

Comment: Click on any other tab and this helps you quickly pick out the questions that matter to you like your life depended on it. Is this an improvement, absolutely, yes

Answer (score -6):

Too many people are solely focusing on the `Interesting` tab. This is more than just that one tab. Everyone is A-OK with the brighter green `x answers` indicator

## What I like

Similar design aesthetics as used currently. Allows for extremely efficient information gathering from a dense pane of information. I can very quickly scan the pages to see which questions I should place focus on.

[image]

Comment: I search for the tags I'm interested in. If I feel like answering a Python question, I search [tag:python]. If I fee like answering a Gtk question, I search [tag:gtk]. I don't really need a yellow eye telling me what I'm interested in. At this point, I'm questioning the purpose of "watched tags". I may just remove all of mine. And I wouldn't call this new responsive design "dense" with information.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin sounds like you don't need watched tags if all you do is search for what topics you want to answer.

Comment: Yes. When I originally joined Stack Overflow several months ago, I though that "watching" a tag meant that you go notifications for new posts in that tag or something (which I think would be really annoying now), so that's why I have watched tags at all. I guess watched tags are just used by the algorithm that chooses what posts to show in the "interesting questions" tab, which I never use anyway. The system may by pretty good, but I'm best of anyone at finding questions that I personally am interested in.